# Add Data Connectors list in Angular web App, just Like "get Data" in Power BI

Tags: angular, powerbi

I want to add a "get Data" component in my Angular 8 Web App to display a list of all available data sources just like in Power BI. I am using Asp.net Core WebAPI at backend.

On clicking "Get Data" I need to display the list of different possible data sources e.g File system (csv, Excel..) , DataBase (Sql Servre MySql, Oracle....) Online (Azure....).
Then I have to get data from the selected source in my app.
Is there any such built in connector by any 3rd party (free / paid) or I have to code all this.

UI in angular and connectivity logic in asp.net core API. Any build-in component that can be integrated with Angular and Ap.net core for this, in DevExpress or in any other 3rd Party.

just like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw8Ye.png)

Any quick response, hint is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Basically you cant directly connect to any data source from angular cause it is client side framework , you can create a API Asp.net Core to do it .Get all connectors as a list from backend then populate it . When selecting a data source , you need to call another API to get data .

Comment: The only thing I can say is that if it is a custom connector, it is located on C:/Documents/Power BI Desktop/Custom Connectors. I don't know about the native ones.

Comment: Thanks AhammadaliPK I know that u cant connect client side framework with datasource. Let me rephrase my question is there any build in connector that can be integrated with Asp.net core for backend and Angular for frontend with all UI and connector Logic

Comment: Dreekun I dont need a custom connector for PowerBI. I need to connect to different sources through my own app.